# Sum from table and round to multiple of 5

Tags: javascript, html

I have script which sum everything in table and adds a new line with a sum.

Now i have this code:

```
var tds = document.getElementById('count2').getElementsByTagName('td');
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
    if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
        sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
    }
}

function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return (ceil($n)%$x === 0) ? ceil($n) : round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}

document.getElementById('count2').innerHTML += '<tr class="sum"><td colspan="2" style="background:#fff;">Wypłacono, podpis:</td><td colspan="4" style="background:#fff;"></td><td>Łącznie</td><td class="count2">' + sum + '</td></tr>';
```

How can I combine this `'+ sum +'` with a function `roundUpToAny()` ? I have tried change `'+ sum +'` to `'roundUpToAny(sum)'` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `' + roundUpToAny(sum) + '`

Comment: Yes, this line of table then doesn't appear

Comment: Do you receive any error in the console?

Comment: You should have a lot of errors in the console due to calling ceil and round wrong, you need to append `Math.` so it ends up like `Math.ceil()`

Comment: I got error "ceil is not defined" 
George, it should be something like 
    return (Math.ceil($n)%$x === 0) ? Math.ceil($n) : round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;

This still doesn't work, but with error "round is not defined"

Comment: You need to do `Math.round` as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your function below.

```
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return (ceil($n)%$x === 0) ? ceil($n) : round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}
```

You're calling the Math objects functions but without the Math object you need to change `ceil` and `round` to `Math.ceil` and `Math.round`

The function should the look like this

```js
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return (Math.ceil($n)%$x === 0) ? Math.ceil($n) : Math.round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}

console.log(roundUpToAny(12));
console.log(roundUpToAny(9));
console.log(roundUpToAny(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.round()` instead.

With `.toFixed()` function you can specify how many values you want after the comma. 
For example `0.23.toFixed(1) === "0.2"`, the result of this is a string, be careful.